# How to pass search parameter, into function that will search a c# collection

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting, collections

Assume I have a collection of the form:

```
List<Member> myMembers= new List<Member>() 
{ 
    new Member(){ID=1,FirstName="John",LastName="Doe"}, 
    new Member(){ID=3,FirstName="Allan",LastName="Jones"}, 
    new Member(){ID=2,FirstName="Martin",LastName="Moe"}, 
    new Member(){ID=4,FirstName="Ludwig",LastName="Issac"} 
};
```

I can sort this list via **FirstName** by using:

```
myMembers.Sort((x, y) => x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName));
```

I would like to do this inside of a function, so that I can pass the desired search parameter.  Something like:

```
public void sortCollection( parameter SearchTerm, List<Member> myCollection )
{
    myCollection ((x, y) => x.SearchTerm.CompareTo(y.FirstName)); 
}
```

Obviously here, I cannot pass in the desired search field this way, but is it possible to do what I am asking?

Comment: You can pass a function `Func<T>` which will contain desired attribute

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a method to do this. Just use `IEnumerable.OrderBy`, as it is, or `Sort`. and work on bigger fish

Comment: Dont think you can deduce a property like that without reflection or some other sorcery. But a question, why are you using a sort predicate for basic built in types like String in this example?

Comment: Please share an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to make sorting as a function with generic search term. C# linq already gave us Linq `OrderBy()` and `Sort()` methods where you can pass predicate based on your requirement. Like `myMembers.Sort(x => x.Id);` or `myMembers.Sort(x => x.FirstName);` or `myMembers.Sort(x => x.LastName);` I believe you are just reinventing the wheels. Correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: Whats wrong with `myCollection.OrderBy(member => member.ID)`? Nice and simple.

Comment: You can follow the `Dynamic Query Expressions` keyword.

Comment: What would a `SearchTerm` be? Is it requested by user? If you want to define your own parameters, you may want to research about how to implement an `IComparer`.

Comment: The reason I want to do this, is so I don't have to retype the same line over and over.  I created this example and is not my real use-case... my real data will have DOZENS of different columns of data in the collection.
If I can create a function, I just past it the sort parameter, and the list, and it will save me from hard-coding in a bunch of different lines that will search on different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic extension method for that and pass [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) delegate to it, which is used as key selector for built-in `Sort` method

```cs
public static void SortExt<T, TValue>(this List<T> collection, Func<T, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    collection.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
}
```

Keep in mind that you should compare the same fields of compared objects.

Example of the usage

```cs
myMembers.SortExt(member => member.FirstName);
```

If you want to compare the `myMembers` collection only, the declaration can be simplified

```cs
public static void SortExt<TValue>(this List<Member> members, Func<Member, TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    members.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
}
```

Another option is to introduce a [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netframework-4.8) delegate instance to store the logic of field comparison and pass it to the `Sort` method. Here you can specify any custom comparison that you want

```cs
Comparison<Member> comparison = (x, y) => x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
myMembers.Sort(comparison);
```

Comment: @pelt Does it answer your question? Do you need more information or details?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YLDr6)

It seems to me that you can use Func<> to be able to dynamic order by.

```
var result = sortCollection(p => p.ID, myMembers);

public static IEnumerable<Member> sortCollection(Func<Member, object> keySelector, List<Member> myCollection)
{
    return myCollection.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[Dynamic Order By in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761350/dynamic-order-by-in-linq)

Comment: This does nothing apart from creates more CIL and makes the user type more text to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing one more wrapper on Linq `.OrderBy()` or `.Sort()` method and calling that where ever you want to sort, use Linq `OrderBy()` or `.Sort()` method

Use `Sort()` like

```
//If you want to sort collection by Id then
myMembers.Sort(x => x.Id); 

//If you want to sort collection by FirstName then
myMembers.Sort(x => x.FirstName);

...
```

To decide between OrderBy()/Sort() read below Q&A thread

[C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832684/6299857)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the built in function?

```
myMembers.OrderBy(m => m.FirstName)
```

If you really want to, you can write your own wrapper around this function, but the call would look more or less identical and would kind of be reinventing the wheel.

something like this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByWrapper<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,TKey> keySelector)
{
    return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

you would call it with:

```
myMembers.OrderByWrapper(m => m.FirstName)
```